# Ruby: Skip element in loop if an exception is raised

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, ruby-on-rails-4, rubocop

I have the following method:

```
def fetch_something
  @fetch_something ||= array_of_names.inject({}) do |results, name|
    begin
      results[name] = fetch_value!(name)
    rescue NoMethodError, RuntimeError
      next
    end

    results
  end
end
```

To its purpose: It fetches a value for a given `name` that can raise an error, in which case it will ignore the `name` and try the next one.

While this works fine I get an error from Rubocop that says:

> Lint/NextWithoutAccumulator: Use next with an accumulator argument in
>   a reduce.

Googling that error leads me to http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/0.36.0/RuboCop/Cop/Lint/NextWithoutAccumulator where it says to not omit the accumulator, which would result in a method looking like this:

```
def fetch_something
  @fetch_something ||= array_of_names.inject({}) do |results, name|
    begin
      results[name] = fetch_value!(name)
    rescue NoMethodError, RuntimeError
      next(name)
    end

    results
  end
end
```

The problem is, that this change breaks the otherwise working method. Any ideas on how to tackle that?

Update: Demonstrational example:

```
array_of_names = ['name1','name2','name3']

def fetch_value!(name)
  # some code that raises an error if the name doesn't correspond to anything
end

fetch_something

# => {'name1' => {key1: 'value1', ...}, 'name3' => {key3: 'value3', ...}}
# 'name2' is missing since it wasn't found durcing the lookup
```

Comment: What about trying `next(results)` instead?

Comment: @user12341234 This breaks it as well.

Comment: perhaps you could show sample input/output to gauge the intended behavior?

Comment: @user12341234 Added example

Comment: Severin, see @user12341234 answer. I didn't know, that you don't need keys without values in result hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your example code, it seems that `next(results)` does fix the issue for me. I've used some test code that throws a `KeyError` instead of `NoMethodError` or `RuntimeError`, but the idea is still the same:

```
@array_of_names = ['name1','name2','name3']

def fetch_value!(name)
  {'name1' => 'n1', 'name3' => 'n3'}.fetch(name)
end

def fetch_something
  @fetch_something ||= @array_of_names.inject({}) do |results, name|
    begin
      results[name] = fetch_value!(name)
    rescue NoMethodError, RuntimeError, KeyError
      next(results)
    end

    results
  end
end

p fetch_something
```

This code outputs:

```
{"name1"=>"n1", "name3"=>"n3"}
```

Also, I agree with @Алексей Кузнецов that `each_with_object` is probably the way to go whenever your block code mutates the data structure you're trying to build. So my preferred implementation of `fetch_something` might be more like this:

```
def fetch_something
  @fetch_something ||= @array_of_names.each_with_object({}) do |name, results|
    begin
      results[name] = fetch_value!(name)
    rescue NoMethodError, RuntimeError, KeyError
      # error handling
    end
  end
end
```

Note that in my example the `begin`/`end` block is *outside* the assignment to `results[name]` in contrast to @Алексей Кузнецов's example which will assign `nil` to the hash every time an exception occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Just use each_with_object

```
def fetch_something
  @fetch_something ||= array_of_names.each_with_object({}) do |name, results|
    results[name] ||= begin
                        fetch_value!(name)
                      rescue NoMethodError, RuntimeError
                      end
  end
end
```

Comment: That also breaks the original functionality of it.